# Restapi sends "invalid api key" message to client side

Tags: php, ajax, codeigniter, codeigniter-restserver, apiclient

I'm creating a rest api using codeigniter 3 and it's running fine, 
but I'm having problems with how to display

```
{"status":false,"error":"Invalid API key "}
```

on the client side and on the server side, 
 so that when Invalid key can be sent "api key invalid" message to user client

Answer (score 0):

You need to find or add on your database **api_rest_access**

also check the `application/config/rest.php`

and send via Postman, if you are using `Rest API on CodeIgniter3` , you cannot access with `GET`

[image]

Comment: how display message on client side

Comment: this is the path, /application/language/english/rest_controller_lang.php

Comment: $lang['text_rest_invalid_api_key'] = 'Invalid API key %s'; // %s is the REST API key